# Редирект каталогов в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Прошу помощи, т.к. полдня рыл гугл и пробовал разные варианты, но не получается и все тут.

Дано: 
Была категория вида: 
`site.ru/cat-lvl1/cat-lvl2/old cat/`  (да-да, именно с пробелом, так она выглядела во всех ссылках и в sitemap и так проиндексировалась поисковыми системами)

Сейчас это категория вида:
`site.ru/cat-lvl1/new-cat/`    (категория сменила вложенность и избавилась от пробела в урл)

Как мне теперь сделать 301 редирект в .htacceess?

Все варианты, что я пробовал выдавали ошибку.

Заранее всех благодарю!

Прилагаю файл:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes




# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap_fast [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]



### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Прилагаю пример переброски со страницы на категорию:
Пример:

```
RewriteRule ^mebel-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/komplekty-mebeli-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-iz-iskusstvennogo%20rotanga/(.*) /mebel-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[http://afinalux.ru/mebel-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/komplekty-mebeli-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-iz-iskusstvennogo rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-na-4-persony/komplekt-mebeli-iz-isk-rotanga-t198dy137c-w53-brown-41.html](http://afinalux.ru/mebel-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/komplekty-mebeli-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-iz-iskusstvennogo%20rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-na-4-persony/komplekt-mebeli-iz-isk-rotanga-t198dy137c-w53-brown-41.html)

Comment: В данный момент редирект выключен? Или включен, но не работает?

Comment: включен но не работает

Comment: Прописан в файле так, как я указал в вопросе, но переадресует не на товар а на категорию

Comment: В ответе (Update) добавил строчку на вашем живом примере.

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
RewriteRule "cat-lvl1/cat-lvl2/old cat/(.*)"  /cat-lvl1/new-cat/$1 [R=301,L]
```

или так:

```
RewriteRule ^cat-lvl1/cat-lvl2/old%20cat/(.*)  /cat-lvl1/new-cat/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Update**.

```
RewriteRule "mebel-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/komplekty-mebeli-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-iz-iskusstvennogo rotanga/(.*)" /mebel-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/obedennye-gruppy-iz-iskusstvennogo-rotanga/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: В обоих случаях не происходит ничего.

Comment: @DmitryUvarov где лежит .htaccess (в корне сайта, в другом каталоге)? Обрабатывается ли htaccess Апачем (AllowOverride) ?

Comment: Лежит в корне.
Остальные директивы работают как надо.
www>без www, ЧПУ, удаление дублей со слешем, все ок.
Именно с этим вышел затык

Comment: @DmitryUvarov .htaccess целиком можете показать?

Comment: @DmitryUvarov хотя может у вас там должен быть редирект вида `/cat-lvl1/new-cat/index.php$1` или что-то в таком духе.

Comment: Он длинный.
Сейчас кину то, что касается редиректов

Comment: @DmitryUvarov добавьте его в основной вопрос и тэгом для кода обнесите.

Comment: Залил файл в вопрос

Comment: RewriteRule "cat-lvl1/cat-lvl2/old cat/"  /cat-lvl1/new-cat/ [R=301,L]
Такс, поставил это первым в списке и заработало

Comment: Теперь только нужно, чтобы все страницы этой категории не вели на новую категори, а вели на соответствующую страницу

Comment: то есть:
old cat/page1 сейчас ведет на
new-cat/
а надо, чтобы на new-cat/page1

Comment: @DmitryUvarov обновил в ответе.

Comment: Не получается, все равно кидает на категорию

Comment: написал в вопрос примеры конкретной страницы